# What is the best way to do a code review across multiple commits, with TortoiseHg?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

The problem that I'm running into is that I have some code reviews to do, with ~10 commits per review.  It's an active repo with constant commits from developers.  I have TortoiseHg filtering my changesets so that I am looking only at the ones that I care about.

What I would like to see is the difference between the changeset before the first change, and the last (without all the non-related changesets showing).  I simply want to see the final results of all these changes.  I don't care that there was some horrible code in changeset 1, that was fixed in 3.  I just want to see the diff of what ultimately got merged through all these changesets.

I feel like I'm missing the obvious, and this isn't a bright question.  Nevertheless, I'm asking anyways.  Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about 1.1.8, as I'm using the 1.9/2.0 candidate release, but I believe you could left-click on changeset1, right-click on revision3 and select visual Diff. This should open your diff tool of choice and only show you the diffs between the 2 versions.

When I did this in the newer tortoise, it opened BeyondCompare in directory compare mode, with revision1 on one side, and revision2 on the other.

Comment: This works in 1.5 as well. Another nifty asset along with diffs is if you want to see who and when a line was edited. Just right click a file in a changeset and click "Annotate file".

Comment: Unfortunately that shows all the changes between the revisions, not just localized to these changesets.

Comment: Obviously I'm not understanding quite what you're after, then. Are you looking for the changes as if you transplanted 3 onto 1, thereby removing any impact of changeset2? If so, then I think the only way would be to transplant, do a diff, and then strip the transplant (or do this in a clone that you subsequently discard)

Comment: If your teammates are willing to use branches or bookmarks to keep parallel lines of work separate, you can diff across multiple revisions in a particular branch without the unrelated changes appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't merge in between commits and diff off the developers clone between start and finish changesets.

Or If merges occured, update and merge everything and then take the entire codebase (or just changed files) and dump it onto a clean tip clone (make sure you are working with the same version to avoid overwriting anything). Recommit all at once.